# How to get first value less than threshold value from hash in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash which contains unixtime as key and volume as values.

I need to fetch unixtime and volume pair from the hash in which the volume is less than `threshold` value (threshold value I am defining in the beginning) and the pair is been occurred in first place of the hash.

Below is my script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

use List::Util qw(reduce);
use POSIX qw( strftime );

my $threshold = 20;

my %hash = (
          '1596561300' => '19',
          '1596561306' => '12',
          '1596561312' => '17',
          '1596561318' => '20',
          '1596561324' => '23',
          '1596561330' => '11',
          '1596561336' => '16',
          '1596561342' => '15',
          '1596561348' => '13',
          '1596561354' => '17'
);

my $key = reduce { $hash{$a} <= $hash{$b} ? $a : $b } keys %hash;
my $val = $hash{$key};

$key = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime($key));

print "Key=>$key :: Value=>$val\n";
```

In above script I am able to get unixtime, volume for a minimum hash value out of all the values(volumes) from hash. i.e.,

```
Key=>2020-08-04 18:15:30 :: Value=>11
```

But I need to fetch the value which is less than the threshold value occurred in first/minimum hash key.

For above example it should fetch ('1596561300' => '19') i.e.,:

```
Key=>2020-08-04 18:15:00 :: Value=>19
```

How can I fetch that? TIA.

Comment: can you please tell if you have two entries  (like 17 value) `'1596561300' => '19', ` which equals to `'2020-08-04 22:45:00' => 19 `  and  for example `'1596561354' => '19'` which equivalent to `'2020-08-04 22:45:54' => 19`  in this case which value you are going to consider?

Comment: @amitbhosale : I should consider the one which occurred first. i.e., `'2020-08-04 22:45:00 => 19'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, all you need to do is make a pass through the hash, checking the values for whether they're under the threshold, and remembering the earliest timestamp which fits that criterion:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    
  
use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX qw( strftime );

my $threshold = 20;
my %hash = (
          '1596561300' => '19',
          '1596561306' => '12',
          '1596561312' => '17',
          '1596561318' => '20',
          '1596561324' => '23',
          '1596561330' => '11',
          '1596561336' => '16',
          '1596561342' => '15',
          '1596561348' => '13',
          '1596561354' => '17'
);

my $earliest;

for (keys %hash) {
  # Ignore any entries with a volume above the threshold
  next if $hash{$_} >= $threshold;

  $earliest //= $_;  # Initialize it if it doesn't have a value yet

  $earliest = $_ if $_ < $earliest;
}

die "No volumes under threshold" unless defined $earliest;

my $formatted = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime($earliest));
print "Key=>$formatted :: Value=>$hash{$earliest}\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make one pass through the hash (without sorting) by checking that the value is less than your threshold and the key is less than your last captured key.

I'm just throwing this out without a syntax check or compiler:

```
my $threshold = 20;
my $last;
for my $key (keys %hash) {
  if ($hash{$key} <= $threshold && $key < ($last //= $key)) {
    $last = $key;
  }
}

if ($last) {
  printf "Key=>%s :: Value=>%s\n",
      strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
      localtime($last)),$hash{$last};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pairmap and unpairs methods provided by https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util#pairmap

> pairmap : Similar to perl's map keyword, but interprets the given list as an even-sized list of pairs. It invokes the BLOCK multiple times, in list context, with $a and $b set to successive pairs of values from the @kvlist.Returns the concatenation of all the values returned by the BLOCK in list context, or the count of the number of items that would have been returned in scalar context.

> unpairs : The inverse function to pairs; this function takes a list of ARRAY references containing two elements each, and returns a flattened list of the two values from each of the pairs,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(pairmap unpairs min);
use POSIX qw( strftime );
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

my $threshold = 20;

my %hash = (
          '1596561300' => '19',
          '1596561200' => '12',
          '1596561312' => '17',
          '1596561318' => '20',
          '1596561324' => '23',
          '1596561330' => '11',
          '1596561336' => '16',
          '1596561342' => '15',
          '1596561348' => '13',
          '1596561354' => '17'
);


# my @list = pairmap { BLOCK } @kvlist;
# parimap invokes the BLOCK multiple times => checking value equal to threshold-1 
# and retrun list 
# my @kvlist = unpairs @pairs
# unpair method takes a list of ARRAY references containing two elements each, 
# and returns a flattened list of the two values from each of the pairs,
my %h = unpairs (pairmap { ($b == ($threshold-1)) ? [$a ,$b] : () } %hash);

# if hash is having mutiple same values then get min key from hash
if (%h) {
    my $min_key = min(keys(%h));
    print "\n Key : ", strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime($min_key)) ," and Value :", $h{$min_key} , "\n";
} else {
    print "\n Not found data \n";
}
```

> Output

```
 Key : 2020-08-04 22:45:00 and Value :19
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can avoid sorting the hash by key:

```
foreach my $k (sort keys %hash) {
        if( $hash{$k} <= $threshold ) {
                print "Key=>", strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime($k)),
                        ":: Value=>", $hash{$k}, "\n";
                last;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the hash to flip the keys and values, and then count backwards from your threshold until you find one that exists.

```perl
my %reversed = reverse %hash;
my $needle   = $threshold - 1;

$needle-- until exists $reversed{$needle};

my $key = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime($reversed{$needle}));
my $val = $needle;

print "Key=>$key :: Value=>$val\n";
```

I don't think I've ever used [`until`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/until.html) before, but this seems to read better than `while not exists`.

Output with threshold `20` is

```
Key=>2020-08-04 18:15:00 :: Value=>19
```

Comment: Note that reversing the hash is only reliable if all hash values are unique.  If there are duplicates, then turning them into keys (with `reverse`) causes a key collision and one will overwrite the others.  In the example data from the question, there are two entries with the value 17, so one of those timestamps is lost.

Comment: @DaveSherohman true, I didn't see that. However the question then is which one OP wants. Your solution has the same collision problem, because you're not sorting. So you get random (depending on Perl version) key order. Since OP doesn't say they want the earliest of them, I think you're making an assumption too, although yours is much better than mine. But I think the question is unclear.

Comment: The question states _"I need to fetch the value which is less than the threshold value occurred in first/minimum hash key."_, which I read as stating that he wants the earliest qualifying timestamp. And if you think there are problems with my answer, please comment there, since that discussion isn't related to your answer.